# Track URL components HTTP Request/Response

Tags: javascript, jquery, http-headers, xmlhttprequest

How to track an URL components HTTP request/response? I want either browser dependent or cross-browser solution and using client-side language.

Give some hint to kick-start my next project.

Comment: request.responseText
request.getAllResponseHeaders()
request.status
request.responseText
we can get above mentioned sample details with XMLhttp request using javascript and you track the request and response using those methods

Comment: sample output of getAllResponseHeaders()..for one of the online example using XMLHttpRequest
Date: Sat, 11 Jun 2016 07:34:58 GMT
Content-Encoding: gzip
Last-Modified: Thu, 17 Sep 2015 12:15:18 GMT
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Etag: "633a658442f1d01:0"
Vary: Accept-Encoding
X-Cache: HIT
Content-Type: text/plain
Cache-Control: public,max-age=3600,public
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 258

Comment: @NagaSaiA Could you please provide an example in fiddle.

Comment: http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/MeywWd

Comment: Hope this is helpful for you